# Zend Framework: Getting request object in bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, request, bootstrapping

How do I get the request object from inside the bootstrap file?

I can try this methods but not work.

```
$request= new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$request = Zend_Controller_FrontController::getInstance()->getRequest();
```

Answer (score 12):

If you really want to, you may achieve this calling:

```
public function _initRequest()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
    $front->setRequest(new Zend_Controller_Request_Http());

    $request = $front->getRequest();
}
```

However, this should be avoided, because the most data you need from the Response object will be available after the front controller is dispatched (eg. module, controller or action name).

The other variables stored in the Response object are extracted from global arrays such as `$_SERVER`, `$_POST` or `$_GET` which you may *exceptionally* read directly in bootstrap.

But most likely, you want to use Response object in [front controller plugin](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3372):

```
class Your_Controller_Plugin_PluginName extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
     public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
     {
         // do anything with the $request here
     }
}
```

Comment: preDispatch is the proper method to do this.

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't get the request objet, since if you see the dispatch loop, the idea is that the bootstrap are actions prior to execute in a request.

If you need to alter someway of the application use a Controller Plugin to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bootstrap the frontController first, try something like:

```
function initFoo()
{
    $this->bootstrap('frontController');
    $req = $this->frontController->getRequest();
}
```

Comment: No work! Return: "Fatal error: Call to a member function getParam()"

Comment: I think the second line is supposed to be `$this->getResource('frontController')`

Comment: Also, wouldn't this be _initFoo() ?